# Should we refine our page description?

Tags: discussion, scope

I think our page description

> Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences

could be refined. How do you feel about this? Should we update the page description or keep it as it is? Please provide proposals for updates as answers.

Comment: At the very least, we should remove the word "the" there. Nobody talks about "The geology"!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase “those interested in” is very unspecific. Hence I think we would be better off dropping it. I would like to list the top 5 or top 6 discipline tags sorted according their popularity. My proposal is to change

> Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences

to

> Q&A for meteorology, geophysics, geology, oceanography, geochemistry, hydrology etc.

Comment: This is a formulaic text as set by SE team. No need to fix it, I'm afraid.